# Implementations of local regression and local likelihood methods

Tags: c++, python, r, machine-learning

I am looking for an efficient implementation of local regression (LOESS) and local likelihood methods such as local logistic regression (local likelihood methods are discussed, for example, in section 6.5 of [Elements of Statistical Learning](http://www-stat.stanford.edu/~tibs/ElemStatLearn/) by Hastie et. al.).

I would prefer a C++ or Python implementation, but pointers to R (where I know that LOESS is implemented, but I can't find a local likelihood method) or Java would also be appreciated.

Many thanks!

Comment: Hi, have you found a C++ implementation? Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In R there are the 'locfit' and 'mgcv' packages that I would suggest do forms of local regression. I believe the locfit package is simply a syntactic bridge to an underlying C package. (But not C++.)

Comment: locfit does both local regression and local likelihood - thank you very much.

Comment: It's perhaps superfluous, since it is information in the DESCRIPTION file, but Andy Liaw is the current maintainer of 'locfit'.

Answer (score 2):

There's an implementation in github. Given that it's pure python, I'd suggest using pypy as an interpreter.

https://github.com/ali01/loess.py

Also, I would recommend pandas as a general purpose regression tool. I'm not sure it implements LOESS and I'm not familiar enough with the algorithm to suggest an alternative, but pandas is wonderful nonetheless:

http://pandas.pydata.org/

Answer (score 1):

Can't you essentially get a python version of LOESS by using sk.learn's [RadiusNeighborsRegressor](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.neighbors.RadiusNeighborsRegressor.html#sklearn.neighbors.RadiusNeighborsRegressor) function and specifying a custom tricube weighting function for the **weights** parameter?